# php, handle unique URLs

Tags: php, authentication

I need to implement a feature:

1. User wants to register on the site
2. User presses a button "register me fast"
3. Script generates unique link like a "mydomain.com/user/asdfsdfsdfswe3525fsdsdfs" and shows it to the user
4. If later user follow this link - we authentificate user and show index page (so, for example, user can bookmark this link and use it instead of username-pass)

I have some restrictions:

1. Link must be like a "mydomain.com/user/asdfsdfsdfswe3525fsdsdfs". No GET parameters.
2. After user is authenticated and page is loaded - user should see this login url in the browser. So I can't redirect user to the needed page/script

I dont understand how to authentificate user via such link using php.
How to avoid 404 error?

Comment: "How to avoid 404 error?" `.htaccess` file with RewriteRules.

Comment: for restriction #1, you will need to use mod_rewrite to convert the querystring parameter to a "pretty" url

Comment: **1**. bad user signs up. **2**. bad user notices this bad implementation of security. **3**. server gets brute forced. **4**. good users get hacked. Not to mention man in the middle attacks. Dont do it man!!!

Comment: better solution, not great, but better, is to send the authorization code to the user via email. The user clicks on the link and gets registered. You would at least validate the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod rewrite the way i do it, this will make it simpler but difficult at the same time.

.htaccess file_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /main site folder/

    RewriteRule (.*)\.xml(.*) $1.php$2 [nocase] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

/classes/simplifyURL.php file_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

```
<?php

class simpleUrl{

    var $site_path;

    function __construct($site_path){
        $this->site_path = $this->removeSlash($site_path);
    }

    function __toString(){
        return $this->site_path;
    }

    private function removeSlash($string){
        if( $string[strlen($string) - 1] == '/')
        $string = rtrim($string, '/');

        return $string;
    }
    function segment($segment){

    $url = str_replace($this->site_path, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    if( isset($url[$segment]))
        return $url[$segment];
    else
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

top of index.php file_***_*__*_*__*_*___**

```
<?php
include 'classes/simplifyURL.php';

$url = new simpleUrl('/main site folder');
$url1 = $url->segment(1);
$url2 = $url->segment(2);
$url3 = $url->segment(3);
$url4 = $url->segment(4);

?>
```

include pages into index.php based off url_***_*__*_***

```
            <?php

 $pages_dir = 'pages';



 if (!empty($url1)) {

  $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);

  unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);



  $p = $url1;



  if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages))  {

   include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');

  } else {

   echo 'Sorry, page was not found.';

  } 

  } else {

   include($pages_dir.'/home.inc.php');

 }

 ?>
```

This is a huge transformation you would have to make.Anyway, let me explain the section above. It takes the value of the first bit of the url, so right after the domain and checks the folder pages for it, if it can find it, it will display it. so for your case, you would need to create a file called user.inc.php. Put the authentication in it and access the end of the url using the $url2 varible for the long code you have on it. Other wise known as dynamic pages. Hope this helps

This is a lot of work, i don't see whats wrong with GET

Comment: add the required mod rewrite, andyou might get an upvote