# mod_rewrite URL with many variables

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm new to mod-rewrite and I have tried to mod-rewrite this url with no success.

URL structure like this :

```
http://mysite.com/script.php?id=15751890&xp=862297&wm=1721&ls=2725&he=63530&ks=23050&eath=53588&tk=10&ck=john&rk=37
```

I want to mod-rewrite it to :

```
http://mysite.com/script.php?id=15751890
```

Or :

```
http://mysite.com/15751890/862297/1721/2725/63530/23050/53588/10/john/37
```

I followed this http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls and this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

But just can't do it write

What to type in htaccess file

Comment: I assume you mean the other way around - that you want to rewrite the clean URL to the script with query string?  What do you have so far?

Comment: there are no query string ( if I understood you well ) I have GET variables in URL and just want to hide all of them except one using mod-rewrite . they told me that this is how it done

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to write such a rewrite you should be able to use this in your htaccess file. There are probably better ways to handle the URL's however, I'm giving you what you asked for.

**NOTE:** I'm going off of the URL you provided.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) script.php?id=$1&xp=$2&wm=$3&ls=$4&he=$5&ks=$6&eath=$7&tk=$8&ck=$9&rk=$10&%{QUERY_STRING}$ [L]
```

So you can use this type of URL with that rewrite.

```
http://mysite.com/15751890/862297/1721/2725/63530/23050/53588/10/john/37
```

Comment: Yes it does. And you can test it here. http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ You never said what's not working and haven't given an example of any effort you've made. Anyway.. good luck to you.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to my answer to this question:

> [php, handle unique URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354288/php-handle-unique-urls/17354484#17354484)

This will give you this:

```
http://mysite.com/15751890/862297/1721/2725/63530/23050/53588/10/john/37
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to figure out every rewrite combination possible, you should learn the MVC routing method.

This way, you route *everything* to a PHP router, and then direct the request to controllers, etc, as needed.

HTACCESS to rewrite everything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

In your PHP script, you can use: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the requested URI.

Example: http://example.com/foo/bar/95 would rewrite to index.php, and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would then be `/foo/bar/95` - and then you route accordingly.

Typically, your URL structure would be like:

http://example.com/controller/action/param_1/param_2/param_3/etc

Whereas "action" is just another name for a controllers method. How you code it is up to you.